# approximate cos(1/10) with three correct decimals around origin with Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Using the Maclaurin with two derivatives I get the following. Substituting x = 1/10 gives approx 0.9800, but the answers say it should be 0.995.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you need an upper bound for the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder) reminder to be $<0.0005$

Comment: The derivatives of $f$ are evaluated at $0$, not at $x$.  The first derivative should be $\sin(0)=0$.  The second should be $-\cos (0)=-1$.  The signs should be $+$ until you apply the signs of the derivative.  Your calculation is still not right because the second term as written should give $-0.1$ and the third should give about $-0.005$.

Answer (score 2):

A Maclaurin series is a Taylor series expansion of a function about $0$,

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)\cdot x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}\cdot x^2+\frac{f'''(0)}{3!}\cdot x^3+\frac{f''''(0)}{4!}\cdot x^4+\dots\tag1$$

For $f(x)=\cos(x)$, we get:

$$\cos(x)=1+0-\frac{x^2}{2}+0+\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots\tag2$$

So, when $x=\frac{1}{10}$, we get:

$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)=1-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^4}{24}+\dots=\frac{238801}{240000}+\dots\tag3$$

And:

$$\frac{238801}{240000}\approx0.995004166666\tag4$$

> Note: the error term is given by the terms we did not put into our approximation. The more terms you pick the more accurate it will become.

Comment: Yes I know, the question is why I get an answer different from the one provided.

Comment: @eriksan Look at my edit.

Comment: And now any motivation why we take $3$ terms, not $2$ and not $4$ )) @Jan

Answer (score 0):

The second term of the Taylor series is $f'(0)(x-0)$.  Because the sine is $0$ at $0$ the term is zero.  The third term is $\frac 1{2!}f''(0)(x-0)^2=-\frac 12(0.1)^2=-0.005$.  Adding this to $1$ gives $0.995$.  The series is alternating, so the error is of the sign of and smaller than the first neglected term.  The next term is $\frac 1{4!}\cdot 1 \cdot 0.1^4 \ll .001$, so our three places are correct.

Comment: Why is the "next term" what you wrote, rather than something divided by 3! times 0.1^3?

Comment: Because the third derivative is $-sin(0)=0$, so there is no term with $x^3$

Answer (score 0):

In your series, you write $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ when you should be writing $\cos 0 $ and $\sin 0$.  The reason you stop after the 2nd-order term is that this is an alternating series.  The error is bounded by the next term, $(0.1)^4/4!$, so two non-zero terms are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I see that we have a 2nd-order term. I've also read that the error is bounded by the next term, which I understood to be f'''(c)/3!(x-a)^3 (for some c between ax and a) but everyone, including you, tells me it's the next one is (1/10)^4/4!, how come?

Comment: Most calc texts give two different ways to bound the error of a series.  One is the Taylor remainder (which uses the 3rd-order term here.)  The other is the bound for alternating series, when you're lucky.  Since the non-zero terms here form an alternating series, we get to use this much easier bound.